# Keras: How to define input shape for 1st DENSE layer?

Tags: deep-learning, keras

I am new to deep learning & keras.

Refer to below code.

1. I don't understand why yhat differs when I define the 1st layer input shape as 'input_shape' vs 'input_dim'. yhat should only be (1,1) - a single value.
2. If instead, I use a simple RNN layer as my 1st layer, what should the inputs shape be?

Thank you

````
# univariate one step problem with mlp
from numpy import array
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator

# define dataset
series = array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]) # 10 samples before processing by the Generator

# define generator
timestep = 2
generator = TimeseriesGenerator(series, series, length=timestep, batch_size=8)


# number of batch
print('Batches: %d' % len(generator))
# OUT --> Batches: 1

# print each batch
for i in range(len(generator)):
   x, y = generator[i]
   print('%s => %s' % (x, y))

#OUT:
[[1 2]
 [2 3]
 [3 4]
 [4 5]
 [5 6]
 [6 7]
 [7 8]
 [8 9]] => [ 3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10]
   
#After processing by the Generator, there are 8 samples in 1 batch. 

x, y = generator[0]
print(x.shape)
    
# define model
model = Sequential()

#TensorFlow assumes the first dimension is the batch_size which can have any size so you don't need to define it. The 2nd D is the number of time steps. The 3rd D is the number of features

#1st LAYER with input shape defined by input_shape
#model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu', input_shape= (timestep,1)))

#1st LAYER with input shape defined by input_dim
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu', input_dim=timestep))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

# fit model
model.fit_generator(generator, steps_per_epoch=1, epochs=200, verbose=0)
# make a one step prediction out of sample
x_input = array([9, 10]).reshape((1, timestep))
print(x_input.shape)

yhat = model.predict(x_input, verbose=0)
print(yhat)

# OUT: [[9.3066435, 10.239568]] if 1st layer's shape is input_shape
# OUT: [[11.545249]] if 1st layer's shape is input_dim
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear this, we need to understand the difference between `input_dim` and `input_shape`, both are useful for two main reasons:

1. Ensuring proper shapes are always passed.
2. Initializing the weights without passing any dummy tensors(can call `model.summary()` after defining the architecture).

- `input_shape` is used to tell the model what tensor shape should it expect.
- `input_dim` is used to tell the model the number of dimensions of features.

More info about it is present [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43676678/how-to-calculate-input-dim-for-a-keras-sequential-model).

Coming back to your question, you'd see what the source of error is if you check `model.summary()` for both cases.

Here's your code modified for brevity:

1. Creating dataset:

```py
from numpy import array
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator

series = array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
timestep = 2
generator = TimeseriesGenerator(series, series, length=timestep, batch_size=8)
```

2. Using `input_shape` to define your architecture:

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu', input_shape=(timestep, 1)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

model.summary()
```

Output:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 dense (Dense)               (None, 2, 100)            200       
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 2, 1)              101       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 301
Trainable params: 301
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

3. Using `input_dim` to define your architecture:

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu', input_dim=timestep))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

model.summary()
```

Output:

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 dense_2 (Dense)             (None, 100)               300       
                                                                 
 dense_3 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 101       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 401
Trainable params: 401
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

The problem is with you adding another dimension to your expected shape in `input_shape`. To correct it, you can pass a single-valued tensor as `input_shape=(timestep,)`:

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu', input_shape=(timestep,)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

model.summary()
```

Output:

```
Model: "sequential_2"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 dense_4 (Dense)             (None, 100)               300       
                                                                 
 dense_5 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 101       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 401
Trainable params: 401
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

You can cross-verify the results by fitting and checking with your own tensor as you did above.

The same logic applies to RNN, [here's](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/RNN#input_shape) the input shape that it expects.

Comment: Can I use "input_dim" in a Dense layer with 3D input data? It doesn't seem to work when I tried. For 3D input data in a Dense layer, I can only use input_shape? Thanks!

Comment: `input_dim` expects integer or None, there might be a workaround but I think the simpler option is to directly use `input_shape`